# What conversion do I need to make to this string in python?

Tags: utf-8, type-conversion

I have this string in python:

```
San Juan-BayamÃ³n-Caguas, PR
```

the A3 special characters, what conversion do I need to make to this to change it to its intended format?

Comment: This looks like some UTF-8 data was interpreted as some other encoding (probably Latin1 or something related). The way to "fix" this is to find the place where it's mis-interpreted and use the correct setting there.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Bayamón-Caguas'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'BayamÃ³n-Caguas'` and vice versa: `'BayamÃ³n-Caguas'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'utf-8')` -> `'Bayamón-Caguas'`. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].